# Java Spring Data Many-to-Many returns the result skipping first entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, many-to-many

I'm new to spring data and am currently trying to create a simple bookstore application with different relationship. I have many-to-many relationship between Book and Author

When I call findAll spring it returns the list of books with author where the first and last book in list doesn't have author.

[This is result of debagging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac4oG.png)

This is my Book entity

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "book_title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

...
}
```

Genre Entity

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "author_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "author_name")
    private String name;
    @Singular
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "author_books",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")}
    )
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Data in DB:

[author_books table. Every book has one author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCc5v.png)

Scheme of DB:

```
CREATE TABLE authors
(
    author_id   INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    author_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
  default CHARSET = latin1;


CREATE TABLE books
(
    book_id               INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    book_title            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
  default CHARSET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE author_books
(
    book_id   INT NOT NULL,
    author_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES authors (author_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
  default CHARSET = latin1;
```

I think the problem is in the spring configuration, because I have a similar problem with others many-to-many relationship

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Pass
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

UPDATE

When, on the contrary, I call findAll books, then in principle I do not have a single author in the books

[screenshot of debagging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrUuZ.png)

Comment: Those are some probable issues:
1. Data Verification: Verify the data in your author_books table to ensure that every book has an associated author and that there are no discrepancies in the data. Check for any data entry errors.

2. Initialization Order: Ensure that you are persisting the authors and books in the correct order. Since you are using CascadeType.PERSIST, it's essential to persist authors before associating them with books and persisting the books. If you persist the books first and then associate them with authors, it can result in the behavior you described.

Comment: I have checked the schema and data for the database. First, the author, books, and finally author_books are created. Afterwards, they are filled with data in the same order. I didn't have any data entry errors. When I call books and not authors, then in principle I don’t have a single author in my books

Comment: Ok, I have a suggestion, Could you remove the cascadeType.persist from this line in Book class:
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) and add the following correction in Author class:

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })

Then reinitialize the data, if needed, and see if it's fixed.

Comment: I did this, it doesn't work. The result is the same

Comment: This way you will update both books and authors references correctly.

Comment: Try adding those utility methods and use them for persistance in Author class: public void addBook(Book book) { books.add(book); book.getAuthors().add(this); } public void removeBook(Book book) { books.remove(book); book.getAuthors().remove(this); }

Comment: I pasted the code into the author class because that's where I have a field with the name 'books', but it didn't work either After I did similar thing to books class:     public Book addAuthor(Author author) {
        this.authors.add(author);
        author.getBooks().add(this);
        return this;
    }
But it doesn't work :/

Comment: Well, that's all I can do, to the best of my abilities. You can check this article here: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ also once again make sure your data is correct and you are not overlooking something.

Comment: First, turn on SQL logging to see the SQL issued at each step. Second, you are showing a debugging view of the Set - the set is lazily fetched though, so you have to inspect it to get the data within. Try iterating over it - accessing it should cause your JPA provider to issue a query to fetch the Books (or Authors). If you have issues, show the SQL issued in the the question and the code you are using in the question - maybe simple test case that shows what you are doing if possible.